# Turn New tabPage into New process

Tags: c#, .net, tabpage

I Have i tabbed application called test.exe , and I need to create a new process every time I create a new tab ( something like IE8 do. ). 
So if I have 3 tabs opened, I have 3 test.exe process started.
I see many example but nothing with tabpages..

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Is this a desktop app? If so, which platform - Winforms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [*MAF* (`Managed Add-in Framework`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx) with *WPF*, you can create a *Control* on a different *AppDomain*.

That means, you can create these controls on different processes. Try looking into that.

If you are using *Windows Forms*, there is also a way to get these *WPF* controls to *Windows Forms* controls.

It will be a complex solution involving a bunch of technologies you may have to learn. But hey, you get each tab in different processes.

---

### References:

- [Add-ins and Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384200.aspx)
- [Managed AddIn Framework (System.AddIn) with WPF](http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2008/10/12/managed-addin-framework-system.addin-with-wpf.aspx)
- [Kent Boogaart on MAF](http://kentb.blogspot.com/search/label/MAF)
- [Source Code for Matthew MacDonald's book Pro WPF](http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4538) has a decent example solution you can look into.